# Browser Extension: Attempting to replace page content and not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my extension to automatically change all content with "views" into "Views hidden" and something similar for "watching" (live streams), but when I run the extension it seems to do nothing. I'm thinking it might have something to do with me not knowing the permissions required or some other thing, but I can't seem to figure it out. This is my first time using javascript.

manifest.json

```json
{"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "SimplyWatch",
    "description": "Simply watch YouTube videos without any views, comments, or ratings data displayed for an experience unbiased by others' opinions.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "Diamivore",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "tab-icon.png",
        "default_title": "SimplyWatch",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```js
const text = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, a, span')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].innerHTML.includes('views')) {
            text[i].innerHTML = "Views hidden"
        } else if (text[i].innerHTML.includes('watching')) {
            text[i].innerHTML = "Watchers hidden"
        }
    }
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you looking for the string in the right case? `views` will not be found if the string is `Views` for example. You may need to use `toLowerCase()` on the string first before you check it. And I would swap `innerHTML` for `textContent`.

Comment: Every time I see "views" on youtube, they're always all lowercaps. I had thought of that already, but I didn't think it would pose a problem because I never saw it as "Views".

Edit: textContent did nothing either, but I'm going to keep that anyways.

Comment: First try adding `"<all_urls>"` to your permissions array - see if that helps. The other thing is that `DOMContentLoaded` might not work because the content might be being added in via AJAX which is why it's not being picked up immediately. You may have to use a timeout to wait for it, or a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I've tried that, and I might have done something wrong (I don't fully understand it), but it didn't seem to work.

`var target = text;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        view();
    });
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

observer.observe(target, config);`

I've added this to the end of the code and created a function out of the `for` loop that replaces it all (named view).